# How to query assets transactions with cardano-graphql?

Tags: cardano-graphql

query assets transaction with cardano-graphql, e.g blockforst api [https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/assets/{asset}/transactions](https://cardano-mainnet.blockfrost.io/api/v0/assets/%7Basset%7D/transactions)

Comment: describe with more details your question

Answer (score 1):

Cardano GraphQL API documentation: https://input-output-hk.github.io/cardano-graphql/

Example requests: https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql/tree/master/packages/api-cardano-db-hasura/src/example_queries

To find all `Transaction` objects related to an `Asset`, you can use the `transactions` query and filter for a specific `Token` in the `TransactionOutput` using the `where` clause.

There is an example in the project wiki that does the same but filters for `Block` number:
https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-graphql/wiki/Interacting-With-The-API

Answer (score 0):

You can also play with GraphQL on ADANATOR, it has this graphical query builder which is pretty useful:

https://adanator.com/graphiql